# Does CMake's set(... PARENT_SCOPE) only set a variable value one scope upward?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-scopes

I am new to cmake. I am using `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)` Following is the structure of my code:

```
Root
    |CMakeLists.txt
    |Subdirectory
         |CMakeLists.txt
         |Sub-subdirectory
               |CMakeLists.txt
```

I store some `.cpp` files in `varname` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for Sub-subdirectory: `set(varname FILES PARENT_SCOPE)`. I would like `varname` to be accessible in the Root `CMakeLists.txt` file. However, the option `PARENT_SCOPE` only makes them accessible one directory up, in Sub-directory, but not in Root. Is there a way to make the files accessible in Root?

One alternative I could find is using `file(GLOB ...)` however `GLOB` is not recommended by cmake developers so I want to avoid using it.

Comment: Why do you want to pass this kind of info to the parent directory at all? It's possible to use files that are not located in the exact same directory as the `CMakeLists.txt` file to as sources to a cmake target, e.g. `add_executable(my_exe Subdirectory/Sub-subdirectory/foo.cpp)`. Furthermore it's possible to create a library target in the (sub)subdirectory, whether as a `STATIC` or `OBJECT` or even as `INTERFACE` lib with sources attached with `target_sources(... INTERFACE ...)`; Imho `CMakeLists.txt` files shouldn't be used just to create a list of source files.

Comment: Also note that a list of sources collected in a subdirectory and used in the root dir would still require you to use paths relative to the root dir or absolute paths. It's not too complicated to add the proper prefix or make the paths absolute, but it won't provide the desired benefit, if you just want to keep your paths short...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `PARENT_SCOPE` for the `set` command only sets the the variable value in the parent scope of the scope it is used in. If you want to go up multiple parent scopes, each scope has to copy the variable value up until it has reached the desired scope. You could use a [global property (`set_property(GLOBAL)`)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html#command:set_property) to avoid that if if so wish: set the global property in a deeply nested scope, then copy out the global property into a CMake variable with [`get_property(GLOBAL)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_property.html). Whether you think such an approach is acceptable or not is up to you and the details of your project. Or, if possible, just set the variable at the scope you want its value to be set at instead of in a deeper scope.

Note that if the end purpose of this variable that stores a list of filenames is only to add it to the list of source files for a target, then I see this as an XY problem. You can be using [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html). I actually find it convenient to combine usage of `target_sources` for source files in subdirectories with `add_subdirectory` because relative paths in CMake-subdirectories are taken as relative to the path of the subdirectory.